# Error executing DDL "insert into ..." via JDBC Statement in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a simple Spring Boot project, and I try to load some data from an import.sql file.
The table is created from the entity, but the data isn't loaded and I receive this error below. The problem is only for MySQL, for H2 there is no error.

```
2022-06-18 15:37:05.457 DEBUG 16272 --- [           main] o.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope     : Scoping TypeConfiguration [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfigur
ation@7b3085a3] to SessionFactoryImpl [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@c1a74d]
Hibernate: 

    drop table if exists currency_exchange
Hibernate: 

    create table currency_exchange (
       id bigint not null auto_increment,
        conversion_multiple decimal(19,2),
        environment varchar(255),
        currency_from varchar(255),
        currency_to varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
2022-06-18 15:37:05.874  INFO 16272 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'file:/D:/cloud-project/cur
rency-exchange-service/target/classes/import.sql'
Hibernate: 
    insert into currency_exchange
2022-06-18 15:37:05.896  WARN 16272 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Err
or executing DDL "insert into currency_exchange" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "insert into currency_exchange" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Fin
al]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applyImportSources(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:514) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]       
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Fin
al.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Fi
nal]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.
Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:
58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[s
pring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3
.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.2
0]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.
20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-be
ans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans
-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.
3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.
20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]        
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3
.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]        
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3
.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0
.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at com.gab.microservices.currencyexchangeservice.CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication.main(CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]        
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syn
tax to use near '' at line 1
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Fin
al]
        ... 33 common frames omitted

Hibernate:
    (id, currency_from, currency_to)
2022-06-18 15:37:05.909  WARN 16272 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Err
or executing DDL "(id, currency_from, currency_to)" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "(id, currency_from, currency_to)" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Fin
al]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applyImportSources(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:514) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]       
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Fin
al.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Fi
nal]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.
Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:
58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[s
pring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3
.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.2
0]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.
20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-be
ans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans
-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.
3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.
20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]        
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3
.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]        
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3
.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0
.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at com.gab.microservices.currencyexchangeservice.CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication.main(CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]        
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syn
tax to use near 'id, currency_from, currency_to)' at line 1
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Fin
al]
        ... 33 common frames omitted

Hibernate: 
    values (10001, 'USD', 'INR')
2022-06-18 15:37:05.959  WARN 16272 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Err
or executing DDL "values (10001, 'USD', 'INR')" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "values (10001, 'USD', 'INR')" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Fin
al]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applyImportSources(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:514) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]       
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Fin
al.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Fi
nal]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.
Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:
58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[s
pring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3
.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.2
0]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.
20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-be
ans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans
-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.
3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.
20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]        
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3
.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]        
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3
.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0
.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at com.gab.microservices.currencyexchangeservice.CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication.main(CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]        
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syn
tax to use near '(10001, 'USD', 'INR')' at line 1
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
```

This is the entity:

```
package com.gab.microservices.currencyexchangeservice.bean;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class CurrencyExchange {
    @NonNull
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "currency_from")
    private String from;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "currency_to")
    private String to;

    @NonNull
    private BigDecimal conversionMultiple;

    private String environment;
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: currency-exchange
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      username: gigi
      password: test1234
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:6666/testdb?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: test1234

server:
  port: 8000

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization: true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql: true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type: trace
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create
spring.datasource.initialization-mode: always
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

import.sql

```
insert into currency_exchange
(id, currency_from, currency_to)
values (10001, 'USD', 'INR');
```

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.gab.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>currency-exchange-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>currency-exchange-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I don't think the problem is the dialect, because it creates the table, only the data isn't loaded in the table. I'm using `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`, if I change the value for dialect it doesn't create the table. Any feedback will be apreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the insert query has been read like 3 separate queries. Try to change the `import.sql` to:

```
insert into currency_exchange(id, currency_from, currency_to) values (10001, 'USD', 'INR');
```

Not sure why you have the error though, I've tested it with the latest Hibernate ORM 5.6.9.Final and it worked fine.

Maybe it's a bug in the version you are using (should be 5.4.32).
Or maybe there's something else in the import.sql?

Comment: Thank you man! If I write the query on a single line it's working.